# ORMLite does not know how to store class

Tags: android, parent-child, ormlite, database-table

Item

```
@DatabaseTable
public  class Item {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
        public Enclosure enclosure;
}
```

Enclosure

```
@DatabaseTable
public   class Enclosure {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId= true, columnName = "id", canBeNull = false)
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String url;
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    protected ForeignCollection<Item> items;
}
```

R.raw.ormlite_config.txt

```
#################################
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.rssproject.Item
tableName=rssitems
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=enclosure
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
#################################
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.rssproject.Enclosure
tableName=rssenclosure
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=url
indexName=rssenclosure_string_idx
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
```

**DatabaseHelper**

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }
```

insert:

```
 List<Item> list = daoRuntimeItem.queryForAll();
                daoRuntimeEnclosure.create(item.getEnclosure());
                daoRuntimeItem.create(item);
```

Error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store class com.rssproject.Enclosure for field enclosure. Use another class or a custom persister.
```

Comment: your ormlite_config.txt is not up to date : the fieldName=enclosure is not marked as foreign. Does a clean build fix your problem ?

Comment: @mithrop I wrote this file by myself

Comment: Oh ! what a bad idea to do this :) Please take a look here (I am sure you already do this as you are able to write the file) : http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android and please follow the instructions about the `DatabaseConfigUtil` ;) Do you have any particular reasons for not using it (technical constraints, not integrated in build phase...) ?

Comment: @mithrop I have error **Could not find raw directory which is typically in the res directory**

Comment: @mithrop where should be located file **DatabaseConfigUtil.java** ?

Comment: @mithrop I have set "Working directory" to /your_workspace/your_project/app/src/main , it works, thanks

Comment: @mithrop A lot of thanks for you, my code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in your comment, you wrote the `ormlite_config.txt` manually, which is a bad idea. ORMLite provides an utility to write that file for you, which be a lot easier :)

Please take a look at this page to have more information : http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config